# Copy and in-place transformation of strings to lowercase/uppercase

Tags: c++, template

I have the following code that transforms a string to upper/lowercase:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <functional>

namespace ae
{
    template <typename StrT>
    auto toLower(StrT& str)
    {
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](const auto& c)
        {
            static const auto loc{ std::locale() };
            return std::tolower(c, loc);
        });
    }

    template <typename StrT>
    auto toUpper(StrT& str)
    {
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](const auto& c)
        {
            static const auto loc{ std::locale() };
            return std::toupper(c, loc);
        });
    }

    template <typename StrT>
    auto toLowerCopy(StrT& str)
    {
        auto newStr{ str };
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), newStr.begin(), [](const auto& c)
        {
            static const auto loc{ std::locale() };
            return std::tolower(c, loc);
        });
        return newStr;
    }

    template <typename StrT>
    auto toUpperCopy(StrT& str)
    {
        auto newStr{ str };
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), newStr.begin(), [](const auto& c)
        {
            static const auto loc{ std::locale() };
            return std::toupper(c, loc);
        });
        return newStr;
    }
}

// Example usage
int main()
{
    std::wstring my_str{ L"Test" };
    ae::toLower(my_str);
    std::wcout << my_str << std::endl;

    std::string my_str2{ "This is a test aswell" };
    auto new_str{ ae::toUpperCopy(my_str2) };
    std::cout << new_str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

All of the 4 functions are pretty much exact copies of each other, just minor variations. I dont want to repeat myself in this way, but im unsure how to make one function that does all of this functionality. How can I improve the code?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is combine the two methods `toLower` and `toUpper` into one method, say `transform`, to which you pass the method by which to transform (`std::tolower` or `std::toupper`) as arguments. The same can be done for `toUpperCopy` and `toLowerCopy`. Passing functions allows you to be more flexible as you are now able to not only use `std::tolower` and `std::toupper` but also any other function which transforms a character.

You can combine everything into one method and use something like a boolean parameter to tell if it should copy or not but I would advise against it. The functions are short functions so they will still be readable and you keep the responsibility for copying in a separate function.

Passing the functions would look something like this:

```cpp
namespace ae
{
    template <typename charT>
    auto transform(std::basic_string<charT>& str, charT charMap(charT, const std::locale&))
    {
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [&charMap](const auto& c)
        {
            static const auto loc{ std::locale() };
            return charMap(c, loc);
        });
    }

    template <typename charT>
    auto transformCopy(std::basic_string<charT>& str, charT charMap(charT, const std::locale&))
    {
        auto newStr{ str };
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), newStr.begin(), [&charMap](const auto& c)
        {
            static const auto loc{ std::locale() };
            return charMap(c, loc);
        });
        return newStr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring my_str{ L"Test" };
    ae::transform(my_str, std::tolower);
    std::wcout << my_str << std::endl;

    std::string my_str2{ "This is a test aswell" };
    auto new_str{ ae::transformCopy(my_str2, std::toupper) };
    std::cout << new_str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I changed the template variable from `StrT` to `charT` as the `charT` was needed for the `charMap`. Using both `StrT` and `charT`, the compiler was not able to infer the template argument for `charT` so you had to manually add the template arguments each time you called `ae::transform`.

Answer (score 1):

A way to shorten your code is to extract common parts — the `tolower` and `toupper` closures and general `transform` and `transform_copy` utilities, in this case: (note that I used `std::locale::classic()` instead of the recently installed global locale)

```
namespace ae {
    struct to_lower_t {
        template <typename CharT>
        CharT operator()(CharT c) const
        {
            return std::tolower(c, std::locale::classic());
        }
    };
    inline constexpr to_lower_t to_lower;

    struct to_upper_t {
        template <typename CharT>
        CharT operator()(CharT c) const
        {
            return std::toupper(c, std::locale::classic());
        }
    };
    inline constexpr to_upper_t to_upper;

    template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Functor>
    void transform(std::basic_string<CharT, Traits>& str, Functor&& functor)
    {
        for (auto& c : str) {
            c = std::invoke(functor, c);
        }
    }

    template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Functor>
    auto transform_copy(std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>& str, Functor&& functor)
    {
        std::basic_string result{str};
        transform(str, functor);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now the converter functions can be provided as wrappers around these.

Also, please apply `remove_if(std::not_fn(needed))`, `sort`, and `unique` to these include directives:

> ```
> #include <iterator>
> #include <algorithm>
> #include <type_traits>
> #include <vector>
> #include <vector>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>
> #include <locale>
> #include <functional>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Passing (most likely) chars by const-ref is, generally, inefficient.
2. In-place can be done in-place, i.e. via `std::for_each`, or a range-for.

Comment: In what way is it inefficient?